# How can i import active admin controllers to my active support test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, activesupport

I want to use this at my test file:

```
@controller=Admin::PostsController
```

but it says:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Admin::PostsController
    /media/mydata/projects/proj/test/proj_test.rb:23:in `test_activ'
```

I suppose it has failed to import `PostsController`. How can I do that?

Note: from rails console I can access:

```
Admin::PostsController
```

Comment: require 'test_helper' do you use it?

Comment: it should be `@controller=::Admin::PostsController`